# Show that a set is denumerable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I have the following question:

> Let $A=\{x:\exists m,n \in\mathbb{Z} \text{ such that } x=m+n\sqrt{p}\}$, where $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a fixed prime. Show that $A$ is denumerable.

I hope someone can solve this question.

thanks

Comment: what does $p$ got to do with it?

Comment: @Mud: I suspect the OP means $m+n\sqrt{p}$. Anyway, what have you tried?

Comment: Check what you wrote: where does  the prime $\,p\,$ appear in the definition of $\,A\,$ ...?

Comment: tags are confusing me... is this a real analysis question?

Comment: yes it is from real analysis about countable set

Comment: sorry about some mistake i did now is correct question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define the map:
$$f\colon \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to A,\qquad (m,n)\to m+n\sqrt{p}$$
then $f$ is clearly surjective and since $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is denumerable then $A$ is also denumerable.

Comment: please explain more

Comment: It's a theorem. If $X$ is denumerable and exists $f:X\rightarrow Y$ surjective, then $Y$ is denumerable.

Comment: Is "denumerable" the right word? I always thought it was "enumerable".

Comment: For all $x\in A$ there's by definition of the set $A$ a pair $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ s.t $f(m,n)=x$ and then the cardinality of $A$ is ''less than'' the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ which is denumerable.

Comment: @Integral I don't know if I can say this in english: $A$ is at most denumerable but this definition exists in the french jargon ''au plus dénombrable'' and it means $A$ is finite or denumerable

Comment: I speak portuguese, and here we say "enumerável" for "denumerable"...that's why a made a confusion, but I do understand now.

Comment: The English term for "finite or denumerable" is "countable".

Comment: @dfeuer ah ok thank's for this precious information so there's not the term enumerable?

Comment: It's a perfectly good word, with various uses in mathematics and elsewhere, but for the specific sense of having the cardinality of the natural numbers, the best term is denumerable.

Comment: @leenaadam You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $A= \bigcup\limits_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \{m+n\sqrt{p} \}$ is a countable union of singletons.